# Hahn Banach Theorem implying existence of a nonzero linear functional taking 0 in a linear subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, unbounded-operators, hahn-banach-theorem, geometric-functional-analysis

I am reading this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/05ce/b32839c26c8d2cb38d5529cf7720a68c3fab.pdf). In the proof of theorem 1, it is stated

> By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is a bounded linear functional on $C(I_n)$, call it $L$, with the property that $L\ne 0$ but $L(R) = L(S) = 0$.

$C(I_n)$ is space of continuous functions on $[0,1]^n$. $S$ is a linear subspace in it. $R$ is the closure of $S$.

Can you explain to me why this statement is true?

Comment: This is true as long as $R$ is not the entire space. What version of the Hahn-Banach Theorem do you know? There's one that's almost exactly this statement.

Comment: I was looking at Rudin 1991. Also Friedman's lemma and theorem. I see on Wikipedia they list something very similar as an important consequence.

Comment: They do assume $R$ is not all of $C(I_n)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M=\{f+af_0:a\in \mathbb R\}$ where $f_0$ is any fixed element not in $R$. Define $T(f+af_0)=a$. If we show that this is continuous on the space spanned by $R \cup \{f_0\}$ we can use Hahn Banach Theorem to get a continuous linear functional which is $0$ on $R$ and has the value $1$ at $f_0$. I will let you verify that $T$ is well defined. Suppose $f_n+a_nf_0 \to g$. If $(a_n)$ is unbounded it has a subsequence ${a_{n'}}$ converging to $\pm \infty$. Dividing by this we get $\frac {f_n'} {a_{n'}} +f_0=0$ which shows that $-f_0$ is the limit of  sequence from $R$ which is a contardiction. Hence $(a_n)$ is bounded and it has  subsequence converging to some $a$. we then get $f_n+a_nf_0 \to g=f+af_0$ for some $f \in R$ and $a=T(g)=\lim a_{n'} =\lim T(f_{n'}+a_{n'}f_0)$. By arguing with subsequences we see that $T$ is continuous.

Comment: What exactly do I have to say about $T$ being well defined?

Comment: Also can I just say $T(\lim [f_n+a_nf_0])=\lim a_n=\lim T(f_n+a_nf_0)$ to show that it is continuous and then say $T$ is linear?

Comment: @ztyh No you cannot show continuity this way because we don't know that $\lim a_n$ exists.

Comment: Can I just use bounded iff continuous? When you prove $(a_n)$ cannot tend to $\infty$, you can say $T$ is bounded and that is the end of the proof?

Comment: @ztyh What Kavi has proved is that, if $f_n+a_nf_0 \to g$ for some $g\in M$, then $(a_n)$ is bounded, which doesn't imply the boundedness of $T$. And for the argument of continuity and subsequence, you may find this [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174281/sequences-subsequences-and-continuity-of-functions) useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is true if $R \neq C(I_n)$. We shall assume that $C(I_n)$ is a real space.

Choose $x_0 \in C(I_n) \setminus R$. $C(I_n)$ is locally convex, $\{x_0\}, R \subseteq C(I_n)$ are disjoint, nonempty and convex sets. Furthermore, $\{x_0\}$ is compact and $R$ is closed, so by the *geometric Hahn-Banach theorem* we can find a bounded functional $L$ on $C(I_n)$ and constants $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ \forall y \in R : L(x_0) \leq \gamma_1 < \gamma_2 \leq L(y). $$

Note that $L \mid_R \equiv 0$, since otherwise we could (by linearity of $L$ and $R$) find a $y_0 \in R$ with $L(y_0) < \gamma_2$, contradicting the inequality above.

Since $L(x_0) < 0$ we have $L \neq 0$, but $L \mid_R \equiv 0$, and since $S \subseteq R$ we also get $L \mid_S \equiv 0$.

This statement holds in general as long as $R \neq X$ is a linear and closed subspace of a real or complex, locally convex topological vector space $X$.